# wso2 das query using a mac address returns incorrect set

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a simple event stream that is persisted with the following attributes:

1. message, type string
2. timestamp, type string
3. host, type string
4. mac_address, type string

where the mac_address and host are index columns.

When I query the table in the Data Explorer with mac_address:00-24-AC-7B-58-01, I get all records no matter what the mac address is. If I change the query to mac_address:01, I get only the records with a mac address ending in 01. I assume the the "-" in the mac address is being interpreted in a special way. I have tried to to put quotes around the mac address, but that does not make any difference. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: can you do the filtering without any issue using host? Only this happen to mac_address column?

Comment: No, I do not get any results when I query using any host:<ip address> or subset of the ip address, or single quoted ip address. The query always returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the query to work using the following:
_mac_address:"00-23-AB-7B-58-01"

Pre-pending the underscore to the field name apparently tells the search to do an exact match. I found this at:

docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Query+Language+Reference

on the bottom of the page.

But, I still cannot seem to get a query to search on an IP address successfully no matter what I try. Maybe the period in the search string is throwing the search off.

As a side note, I found a way to search for the mac address using the restful API, by escaping the quotes as follows:

{ "tableName":"MYTESTIN1", "query":"mac_address:\"00-23-AB-7B-58-01\"", "start":0, "count":100 }